# List all the in-app products for an Apple Store app

Tags: app-store, in-app

Developing subscriptions back-end service for App-Store app, there is a requirement to fetch all available in-app products and subscription for specific App-Store App. The best way is using the rest API call.

I wondering if the App-Store exposes such API. What I expect to have is something similar to what Android provides.

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/inappproducts/list

The Rest API.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/packageName/inappproducts
```

Googling it, didn't bring anything close to what Android has.

Any helpful ideas or develop stuff will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for :
GET [https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/apps/{id}/inAppPurchasesV2](https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/apps/%7Bid%7D/inAppPurchasesV2)

From documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi